# ASP.Net MVC return View with new Instance of Model instead of using Redirect To Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I have a form view which uses a ViewModel. A new view is rendered by Action "New".  When this form is submitted I send back the info to action "Add".

If all actions on DB are successful I want to refresh the view. I create a new instance of viewmodel from inside "Add" action and  do return  View("New",viewModel) . This does not refresh my view. All old values ( that were submitted) remains in the view. 
Is there a way to refresh the page without RedirectToAction method.

I read on another post that ModelState.Clear should not be used as it can have undesirable result.

Thank you,

Mar

Edit 1 - Code Added

```
New

 public ActionResult New(string id)
        {
            var sysId= new Guid(id);
.......
........

  string Details = pDto.Name + "(" + pDto.Code + ")";

            var vm= new ViewModel(id);
            vm.Details = Details;

            return View(vm);
        }



 public ActionResult Add(ViewModel vm)
        {
                        ViewModel vm= vm;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                              var dto= _qRepository.GetFeaturesBy(viewModel.Code);

                if (dto!= null)
                {

                    ModelState.AddModelError("Code", "Code is already in Use.");

                    return View("New", viewModel);
                }

                _productService.AddFeature(..........);
               // ModelState.Clear();  -- this works          
                vm= new ViewModel(vm.pId) { Message = "Code" + viewModel.Code + " was added ......", Details = vm.Details };

            }


          return  View ("New", vm);

        }
```

Comment: are you able to post the code for what you're currently doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try to adhere to the [post-redirect-get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. The only time you don't is when the post failed and you want to return the validation errors so the client can re-post the form. This is what happens when you return a view from a post action method. All those form values are still floating about in ModelState waiting to be used again on the form.

You can use `RedirectToAction("New")` if you want to let user add another item right away. Also, it sounds like both actions should be named `New` and then decorate the post version with an `[HttpPost]` attribute and the PostModel parameter. Things get messy if you post and get between two different actions because then you'd have to remember to explicitly set the action on the html form and also to return the right view on validation failure.

Comment: as this is my first MVC project I would like to stick to best ways and  post-redirect-get seems like the right way. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Your model is being refreshed fine.

The problem is the HTMLHelpers look for data in ViewState and ModelState first before using the new model you passed down.

You almost have no choice BUT to clear ModelState or manually change the ModelState entries yourself.

Comment: will you consider using Clear method safe. It does what I need.

Comment: I use it whenever appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It is rendering with the values attributes filled, or the browser is "autofilling" the form?

The RedirectToAcction will cause a 302 response, and then a new "Get" to the new form.

Comment: I populate view Model with some values when it is first instantiated and I wish to not query again for the same values. This is why I would want to not go to New Action  and populate the new "view model" with parameters (from posted view model)