# Model values no shown updated in the view after a POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following simple (for the purpose of the question) controller/action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    User user = repository.GetUser(id);
    return View(user);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(User user) 
{
    user.Name = user.Name.ToUpper();
    return View(user);
}
```

and the view was generated as Edit for User using regular steps in VS

The problem I'm facing is that whatever has been entered in the Name text-box will be showed back to the user but without uppercase. I have checked and the Edit action for POST is executed and user.Name value become UPPER CASE but .TextBoxFor is still using the value entered by the user which is in lower case.

I have checked also that if I print (without the use of any Html Helper) the value of Model.Name after the POST, it will be in UPPER CASE as I would like the Html.TextBoxFor to behave.

Is that a bug of MVC?

Is there a way of making this work in the way I want, meaning that the action/controller is the piece in the puzzle to decide data values for the View and not the view using the ones in the Request object and ignoring the changes that the controller might have done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use RedirectToAction and pass the Id for the user, it's not a bug, is the POST Behaviour

> Update: You need to persist the information before RedirectToAction as Dismissile said, or use TempData if you do not want to persist.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(User user) 
{
    user.Name = user.Name.ToUpper();
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = user.id });
}
```

Comment: Without persisting the data somehow this is not going to do anything.

Comment: Is there a better solution to this issue besides RedirectToAction?

Comment: I want to point out that the Model instance in the View has the UPPER case value. It is just that the Html helpers are not taking the value from it even when explicitly the expression on TextBoxFor reads as model => model.Name.

Comment: I think the issue is not related with POST but with Helper Html functions

Comment: For clarification, see the chosen answer for this question, about behaviour on POST action. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4620277/743965

Answer (score 0):

You can use ModelState.Remove(nameOfProperty) like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(User user) 
{
    ModelState.Remove("Name");
    user.Name = user.Name.ToUpper();
    return View(user);
}
```

It's will work.